# Main update ordering

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

In my main update function I am checking for controller input, updating the game characters, and handling collision.  My main update function currently looks like:

```cs
// Handle Character/Terrain collision
foreach (ICharacer character in this.CharacterList)
    foreach(ITerrain terrain in this.TerrainList)
        HandleCollision.FixCollision(character, terrain)

// Get controller input
foreach (IController controller in this.ControllerList)
    controller.GetAction();

// Update characters
```

This all works great, but I noticed when I switch the ordering so that the Controller Input is checked before Collision Handling, the characters fall through the floor.

The `controller.GetAction()` method is a series of `if` statements and commands checking for buttons that are being pressed.  If no button is being pressed, it does nothing.

I was wondering why this ordering matters, especially when `controller.GetAction()` does nothing.  I'd be happy to add more code if you want.

Comment: It seems that, when you check controller input before collision handling, your "world" has no colliders at that moment, as you were destroying and creating them each update cycle.

Answer (score 1):

if I'm correct, you are using some kind of line collision (if bottom of your characters touch top of your terran) instead of box collision. in that case happend like on left part of image, character fall out. but if you will use box collision (right side of image), character will collide with terrain. and by calculating how deep he fall you can put character on top of terrain before drawing it.

even if you press 5 times down button before you check for collision, it boxes will still colide.

[image]

i hope this will help you.